# Laravel Send a Notification to C# Application

Tags: c#, laravel

I am looking to create some sort of a function that would send Laravel notifications to C# application. The idea is that whenever a user purchases someone, an administrator is then notified by receiving a notification through a C# application that they would run on their PC. However, at the moment the only way I can think of is by creating a listening server in C# and then just send the data via sockets through PHP. Is there anything else that would be considered a better approach?

Kind Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

You can build an event-driven system. Your Laravel application will be producer which responsible for send events, and C# application will be consumer. There are lots of options to do it.

I would like to recommend [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/). Also, you can easily create a Lambda, then you can add your newest queue as a trigger. When you do this, you will have a serverless architecture, and you won't worry about the scaling part, AWS handles these stuffs. Also, you can check [this](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/event-driven-architecture-with-sqs-and-aws-lambda). It can be a good start point to meet serverless architecture.

Comment: Oh, that's actually brilliant! Thanks for the idea!